# .NET 3.5 optimizations after converting from 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: .net, vb.net, optimization, .net-3.5

I converted our project from .NET 2.0 to 3.5 and am looking for optimizations that can be done utilizing 3.5 framework. What are some of the things I can do with 3.5 as in Datastructures. Also any suggestions in using DataAccess apart from LINQ to SQL.
Any suggestions/pointers would be great. I am not looking at any specific optimization, just a general . I am also using VB.NET :(

Comment: The single biggest optimization you can make is to switch to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link pretty much gives you all of the new VB 9.0 features at a glance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068.aspx

- Implicitly Typed Local Variables
- Object and Array Initializers
- Anonymous Types
- Deep XML Support
- Query Comprehensions Extension
- Methods and Lambda Expressions
- Nullable Types
- Relaxed Delegates

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat Dependant on C#, because you can't write iterators in VB.Net.  But a big performance improvement for me is the Iterator + Extension Method + lambda expression combo.  Iterators were available in .Net 2.0 as well, but when you combine them with the IEnumerable extension methods you suddenly have a very powerful optimization tool.

For example, let's say you have code to read through a file and get all the lines that contain some specific text.  In .Net 2.0 you'd either use `File.ReadAllLines` or iterate over a stream reader.  In .Net 3.5 you can wrap the stream reader with an iterator and write code like this:

```
ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt").Where(l => l.Contains("search text") );
```

Now this isn't all that special, because you could write code that gets close to it in .Net 2.0.  But the really cool thing is you can continue to add filters:

```
var query = ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
                            .Where(l => l.Contains("search text") )
                            .Select(l => int.Parse(l.SubStrin(5,8))
                            .Where(i => i > 10 );

int sum=0;
foreach (int value in query) 
{
    sum += value;
}
```

Pop quiz — how many times will that code iterate over the file results?  The answer is exactly one.  Adding a new `.Where()` or `.Select()` doesn't cause it to loop over the results again.  Rather, it defers the execution to create a sort of pipeline for your enumerable.

To get similar performance in .Net 2.0 you'd have to either write a much longer function that includes opening and reading through the file, have a much more complicated class to implement IEnumerable, or make extensive use of custom delegates that most programmers wouldn't understand.

This allows you to abstract away the code that reads the file in a very simple and very reusable way, such that the language now lends itself to writing efficient code.  The fun part is that you *can* make some use of this from VB.Net: you just have to have a C# assembly somewhere to keep the iterators you want to write, and then your VB.Net code would look like this:

```
Dim query = ReadLines("C:\MyFile.txt") _
                      .Where(Function(l) l.Contains("search text") ) _
                      .Select(Function(l) Integer.Parse(l.SubString(5,8) ) _
                      .Where(Function(i) i > 10 )

Dim sum As Integer = 0
For Each value As Integer In query
    sum += value
Next value
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by optimizations.  Can you clarify a bit?

The 3.5 framework and the corresponding VB.Net compiler was not so much about optimization but much more about the concepts surrounding LINQ (language integrated query).  It's a way of defining a generic query language, somewhat resembling SQL, that can be used on a variety of different sources.

For instance, lets say you had a list of Students and wanted to grab the ones which had a particular name.  Prior to LINQ you'd write something like the following

```
Dim list As New List<Student>()
For Each cur in col
  if cur.Name = SomeName Then
    list.Add(cur)
  End If
Next
```

LINQ greatly simplifies this by letting you write the following

```
Dim result = From cur in col Where cur.Name = SomeName
```

Answer (score 1):

VB 9 has a cool XML primitive type that lets you do:

```
Dim book As XElement = _
    <book category="fiction" isbn=<%= isbnNumber %>>
        <modifiedDate><%= modifiedDate %></modifiedDate>
    </book>
```

Which is pretty cool!  (code taken from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384964.aspx))

Comment: yeah, this is cool. It is the one and only feature (syntax sugar) of VB that I wish was in C#

Answer (score 0):

If you're using remoting or serialization in 2.0 you can switch it over to WCF remoting/serialization now and from what I've read you'll see nice performance increases.